# HortonWorks or Cloudera certification

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, hortonworks-data-platform

Hortonwork and cloudera companies are merged now so, which certification would be better to take? Please share your thought on this one.

Comment: some one down voted this question. I am not sure about the reason and I think its a valid question. Share your comment and down vote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion it depends on your present case and career goals. For example, if you are (looking for) working as an HDP Administrator, no Cloudera certification would be helpful.

Hortonworks certification exams are being re-branded as 'Cloudera HDP certifications' since there is a definite plan to maintain HDP production for a few years.